# Form disappear when I click any link or button how to solve this?

Tags: php

This first form work fine

```
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            <form action="categories.php" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search">
                      </div>

        <div class="form-group">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="search1" value="searchcategory">
                      </div>

                    </div>
```

This second form dissapear when click any link or button in it

```
                      <div class="col-xs-6">
                      <form action='categories.php' method='post';>
                      <table class='table table-bordered table-hover'>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>categories</th>
                        </tr>   
                        </thead>
                   <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['search1'] )){
                        $searchval=$_POST['search'];
                        $querynew="SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_title='$searchval'";
                        $m1 = mysqli_query($connection1,$querynew);
                        $i=0;
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($m1)) {

                        $cat_id1 = $row['cat_id'];
                        $cat_title2 = $row['cat_title'];

                        echo"
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>

                        <td>
                        $cat_id1
                        </td>";


                     if(isset($_GET['edit'.$i.''])){
                         $ab = $_GET['edit'.$i.''];
                         $query1="SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_id=$ab";
                        $m = mysqli_query($connection1,$query1);

                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($m)) {

                        $cat_id2 = $row['cat_id'];
                        $cat_title3 = $row['cat_title'];

                   echo"   
                        <td> 
                       <input type='text' class='form-control' name='txt".$i."' value='$cat_title3'>
                       </td>";

                        }
                     }

                        else{
                        echo"<td>
                        $cat_title2
                        </td>";
                        }
                        echo"
                        <td>
    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='submit".$i."' value='Edit category'>
    </td>
    ";
                         if(isset($_POST['submit'.$i.''])){
                         $abc = $_POST['txt'.$i.''];
                         $query2="UPDATE categories SET cat_title='$abc' WHERE cat_id=$cat_id2";
                        $sm = mysqli_query($connection1,$query2);

                         }

                        echo"    <td>
                         <a href='categories.php?id1={$cat_id1}'>Delete</a>
                         </td>
                          <td>
                         <a href='categories.php?edit".$i."={$cat_id1}'>Edit</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>";


                        $i++;
                        }
                    }

                    ?>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </form>
                    </div>


                     <?php 
                    // Delete category 


                        if(isset($_GET['id1'])){
                        $h = $_GET['id1'];
                        $query = "DELETE FROM categories WHERE cat_id = {$h} ";
                        $delete_query = mysqli_query($connection1,$query);






                          }


                    ?>
```

.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Check your error log..

Comment: no error appear when run

Comment: Hey *PHP Developer*, this is how you align your code while writing code. First align your code properly. Your code is aligned in such a manner where coder as well as viewer will get difficult to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you only have a button called "search1" on form 1 but form 2 does not, and you've wrapped the entire code block with `if(isset($_POST['search1']))`.

Any post from the form on the second page will not display without a button called "search1" in the form on page 2. Or if you click the button called "search2" on page 1, for that matter.

I'm actually not sure what you're really attempting to go for because the code is pretty poor so I can't provide an actually coded solution, rather just point out your error.

Add `var_dump($_POST);` on your second page outside your `if` block and you should see this.

Comment: I search and display data in the same page (one page),idont use serch2 button(for test only) .this is full code

Comment: Any buttons you click in your results table will result in that table being hidden by the conditions I highlighted above in `if(isset($_POST['search1']))`

Comment: yes ,you right,i understand this but how to solve this issue?

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['search1']))` will never be true when you submit a form using a button in the table. Change it to `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`

Comment: the same issue . Form still disapperar

Comment: **the same issue** i used `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`

Answer (score 0):

Put the entire code in a file. like this it will work.

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
                  <form action='categories.php' method='post';>
                      <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="search1" value="searchcategory">
                      </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="search2" value="searchcategory">
                      </div>
                  <table class='table table-bordered table-hover'>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>
                    ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    categories
                    </th>
                    </tr>   
                    </thead>
               <?php


                    if(isset($_POST['search1'] )){
                    $searchval=$_POST['search'];
                    $querynew="SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_title='$searchval'";
                    $m1 = mysqli_query($connection1,$querynew);
                    $i=0;
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($m1)) {

                    $cat_id1 = $row['cat_id'];
                    $cat_title2 = $row['cat_title'];

                    echo"
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>

                    <td>
                    $cat_id1
                    </td>";


                 if(isset($_GET['edit'.$i.''])){
                     $ab = $_GET['edit'.$i.''];
                     $query1="SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_id=$ab";
                    $m = mysqli_query($connection1,$query1);

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($m)) {

                    $cat_id2 = $row['cat_id'];
                    $cat_title3 = $row['cat_title'];

               echo"   
                    <td> 
                   <input type='text' class='form-control' name='txt".$i."' value='$cat_title3'>
                   </td>";

                    }
                 }

                    else{
                    echo"<td>
                    $cat_title2
                    </td>";
                    }
                    echo"
                    <td>
<input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='submit".$i."' value='Edit category'>
</td>
";
                     if(isset($_POST['submit'.$i.''])){
                     $abc = $_POST['txt'.$i.''];
                     $query2="UPDATE categories SET cat_title='$abc' WHERE cat_id=$cat_id2";
                    $sm = mysqli_query($connection1,$query2);

                     }

                    echo"    <td>
                     <a href='categories.php?id1={$cat_id1}'>Delete</a>
                     </td>
                      <td>
                     <a href='categories.php?edit".$i."={$cat_id1}'>Edit</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>";


                    $i++;
                    }
                }

                ?>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                </form>
                </div>


                 <?php 
                // Delete category 


                    if(isset($_GET['id1'])){
                    $h = $_GET['id1'];
                    $query = "DELETE FROM categories WHERE cat_id = {$h} ";
                    $delete_query = mysqli_query($connection1,$query);






                      }


                ?>
```